# How to reference image in React Component NPM module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have made a date picker in react and I am trying to upload it to NPM, and it uses an external svg, but I am having trouble correctly referencing that svg.

So my file directory looks like this:

```
+-- imgs
|   +-- arrow.svg
+-- src
|   +-- Datepicker.jsx
|   +-- index.js
```

Then in Datepicker.jsx I have
`<object style={STYLES.arrow} data="../imgs/arrow.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />`

But then when I install it through npm and try to use it in a project, it says:
`GET http://localhost:8000/imgs/arrow.svg 404 (Not Found)`

It looks like it is looking for the imgs directory in the root of the project instead of in the module itself, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use [`webpack`](https://webpack.github.io/) to simply `require` the data before it compiles:

```
const data = require('../imgs/arrow.svg');

<object style={STYLES.arrow} data={data} type="image/svg+xml" />
```

You will need to do `npm install --save-dev webpack url-loader` or something similar. The `webpack` docs should let you know what you need (linked above).

Your problem is that it's trying to find the data path at *runtime*, when what works better is for it find the data path at *compile time*.

Comment: I am using webpack for my project, but for this module specifically since I am putting it on NPM so that it can be used by others, I was just transpiling it to ES5, so are you saying that I would use webpack to bundle all of the js and images and then upload that bundle to npm?

Comment: That's a pretty common pattern (having, say, a `src` and `dist` folder, where `dist` contains the compiled output). Many existing modules follow that pattern, especially because it then can lessen the dependency requirements for users who use the module.

Comment: So, yes, I would say it may be good to provide the `src` with all of your pre-compiled files, and then a folder `dist` with the compiled output.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer really helped me out here, just wanted to show how I got it to work for me. I have a few React projects that need to share a component, so I've built that component in its own standalone library. Originally, I had been referencing some images in the library via the "typical" `src` method where those static files are being grabbed from a public directory, such as `<img src='icons/down-arrow.svg' />` but, as the OP noted, that doesn't work when the library is imported into the parent project because the parent project will end up looking for the icons based on its own root, not that of the library.

Importing those icons and setting those imports as the `src` attribute did the trick -

```
// src/components/component.js
import React from 'react';
import downArrow from '../../../public/icons/down-arrow.svg';
import rightArrow from '../../../public/icons/right-arrow.svg';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const icon = props.selected ? downArrow : rightArrow;

    return (
        <div>
            <img src={icon} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

In this case, the component would be at `/src/components/component.js` and one of the icons would be at `/public/icons/down-arrow.svg`

Alternately, you could alias the `public` directory in your Webpack config like so

```
// ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            public: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/')
        }
    },
// ...
```

And remove the leading `../`s from your import paths.

Comment: Can you please share the structure of your component-library I am facing same issue

Comment: @Abhi I added a note about the file structure, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separated component:

```
export function BaseIcon(props: any) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={
          require(`../node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${props.name}.svg`)
            .default.src
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and from the component, you can access it directly by passing the name

```
<BaseIcon name={item.name} />
```

Little explanation what `require(`../node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${props.name}.svg`)` returns, that's an object, one of the properties that's `default`. That's the sometimes, in the answers, you can see the `default` at the end. I believe that's not limited just to the `cryptocurrency-icons`, a conclusion while searching for the solution. In my case, the `default` is an object, which has `src` key with a direct path to the source file.

No extra dependencies, at least on `Next.js`, like the `url-loader`, are needed.